# $\det{\begin{bmatrix}\det A & \det B \\ \det C & \det D\end{bmatrix}}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B,C,D \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and let $rank{\begin{bmatrix}A & B \\C & D\end{bmatrix}}=n$.
>
> Prove that $\det{\begin{bmatrix}\det A & \det B \\ \det C & \det D\end{bmatrix}}=0$

I really don't have any idea to solve this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106071/if-operatornamerank-left-beginbmatrix-a-b-c-d-endbmatrix-right?rq=1), you have $det(AD)=det(BC)$. So, QED :)