# Determinant of Block Matrices is Zero

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices

Let $A,B,C,D\in \mathbb{F}^{n×n}$ and let $M=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}$ have rank $n$. If $A$ is nonsingular, show that $M$ is equivalent to $\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\0&D-CA^{-1}B\end{bmatrix}$, and justify why $D-CA^{-1}B=0$.

Show that $det\left( \begin{bmatrix}|A|&|B|\\|C|&|D|\end{bmatrix}\right)=0$ using the above statement.

I have already shown the equivalence part. As well as what happens if $B,C,D$ are nonsingular. I haven't yet proven the $D-CA^{-1}B=0$ and I have to use all of these to prove that the determinant is zero.

Can you help me with this please? Thanks.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106071/if-operatornamerank-left-beginbmatrix-a-b-c-d-endbmatrix-right.

Comment: We cannot help you if you do not show your work on the problem.

Comment: I already tried proving the equivalence part. As well as taking what happens to the matrix if B, C, or D are nonsingular. I have to use these equivalence to show that the determinant is zero

Comment: @Lostinspace Maybe you should also include your comment in the edit. At a first glance i did not vote for reopening (but now I did).